# Как использовать картинки, доступные по ссылке?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Начинаю изучать React и не совсем понимаю, как использовать в коде изображение, доступное по определенному url на сервере? Каждая картинка имеет свой imageId, который содержится в json, прилетающим с сервера.

```
     import {ProductItem} from "../models";

interface ProductProps {
    product: ProductItem
}

const imageURL = "http://localhost:8080/images/"

export function Product({ product }: ProductProps) {
    return (
        <div className="productItem">
            <img src="http://localhost:8080/images/${product.imageId}"/>
            {product.id}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ну так вставьте `imageURL` в `url` в `img`, не понимаю в чём вопрос

Comment: @EzioMercer вопрос в том, что нужно, чтобы в imageURL вставлять нужный imageId, для доступа к изображению. И я не понимаю, как это сделать

Comment: а сейчас вставляется не нужный ?

Comment: как минимум из кода выше заменить ""на ``

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin оно не работает. Т

Comment: в каком плане не работает? не выводит картинку ?  но картинка по адресу `http://localhost:8080/images/idImg` открывается ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin скачивается файл типа "Файл" (как его интерпретирует Windows), который уже можно открыть в браузере

Comment: возможно у вас проблема на стороне сервера с раздачей статики ?